# How to export data from a table having an input inside the mat-cell?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table-exporter

I have a project in Angular material in which I am trying to export the data from a table to an `xlsx` file using the `MatTableExporter` module.

I have the columns `ID`, `Name` and `actions` (edit and delete), but it only shows me the columns ID and actions, the Name column appears empty.

**My problem**: because the Name column appears empty and how can I make the data show? How can I remove the actions column from the `xlsx` file?

This is my `component.html`:

```
<div class="title">Customers</div>
<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="10px" class="m-3">
  <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z8">
  
    <div>
      <button mat-raised-button
        (click)="exporter.exportTable('xlsx')">Export excel
      </button>
    </div>
    
    <mat-table matTableExporter [dataSource]="clients" #exporter="matTableExporter">
    
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients"> {{clients.id}} </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients; let i = index">
          <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" [appearance]="editIndex != i ? 'none' : 'legacy'">
            <input matInput placeholder="{{clients.name}}" [(ngModel)]="clients.name" [readonly]="editIndex!=i">
          </mat-form-field>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
      
      <ng-container matColumnDef="act">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Actions </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element
          <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Edit" (click)="edit(element)">
            <mat-icon class="icon_edit_button">edit</mat-icon>
          </button>
          <button *ngIf="editIndex != i" mat-icon-button matTooltip="Delete" (click)="delete(element)">
            <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </mat-cell>
      </ng-container>

      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let col; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

    </mat-table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

This is my `xlsx` file:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the actions column from the XLS you can add this as a hidden column in the `mat-table` tag. Here you pass in an array of the column indices you want to omit from the XLS:

```
<mat-table ... [hiddenColumns]="[2]">
```

To render the name in the XLS, you can add the line:

```
<span class="cdk-visually-hidden">{{clients.name}}</span>
```

so your second column becomes:

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let clients; let i = index">
  <span class="cdk-visually-hidden">{{clients.name}}</span>
  <mat-form-field floatLabel="never" [appearance]="editIndex != i ? 'none' : 'legacy'">
    <input matInput placeholder="{{clients.name}}" [(ngModel)]="clients.name" [readonly]="editIndex!=i">
  </mat-form-field>
</mat-cell>
```

This adds a hidden field containing the name. Because your using `[(ngModel)]` you have 2 way binding and any changes the user makes to the name in the `input` field, will get reflected in hidden field and therefore in the XLS when you export it.

Here's [a StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mte-demo-xxqmuy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) showing this working. Just change one (or several) of the name fields and hit the "Export excel" button and you should get this:

[image]

Comment: I get a warning that I can't solve: ``depends on 'xlsx / dist / xlsx.mini.min'.
CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts``. I've read that it can be fixed using ``allowCommonJsDependencies``, but I don't know where to add it

Comment: In your angular.json file, try putting it under `architect` > `build` > `options`

Answer (score 0):

I had a different user case. I had to display a set of form elements in a Mat Table and user can edit and submit all of it as an array.

On the click of the button or user action, I get the `FormGrop` Element Array and just converted to my domain object array.

```
this.address.inputRecords=> My domain object  typescript []

let json = JSON.stringify(this.address.inputRecords);

const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(
  JSON.parse(json)
);
const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, worksheet, 'Sheet1');
```